# Shimano STePS Di2 Shifting with Alfine 11 - will it be ever automatic?

Tags: alfine, shimano-di2, steps

The Shimano STePS with Di2 and Alfine 8 received a firmware update this year, which enabled automatic shifting (it was not automatic before).

Does anybody know if Alfine 11 models will receive any firmware updates to switch automatically?

This FAQ from Shimano only mentions the Alfine 8. http://shimano-steps.com/e-bikes/europe/en/service

Comment: Maybe email Shimano?

Comment: I was not able to find any contact e-mail at the Shimano website ... I tried to ask bike builders, but nobody knows yet. It was also by accident that one bike shop mentioned that if we go for the Alfine 11, there is no automatic shifting in the Di2. :-(

Comment: I wonder if you managed to find out the answer? I've read somewhere that Alfine 11 can be used as an 8-gear hub with auto shifting... That wouldn't be ideal but at least could allow someone with a Di2 Alfine-11 experience the auto shifting.
Looking over Shimano's website, not counting some derailleurs (CUES Di2, Deore XT Di2), the only internal geared hub that mentions automatic shifting is the e-bike specific Nexus Inter-5E.

Comment: There's also this press release from 2016 that mentions automatic shifting with "SHIMANO STEPS components (DU-E6001 and DU-E6010) and Nexus-8 Di2 (SG-C6060) sealed hub drive units":
https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/information/news/automatic-gear-shifting-upgrade-for-ebikes-with-shimano-steps-an.html

Comment: Here's the manual for the Shimano software where automatic shifting can be configured: https://si.shimano.com/en/pdfs/um/7J4WA/UM-7J4WA-010-ENG.pdf
It doesn't list compatible derailleurs/hubs, and I couldn't find a definitive answer on which hubs could work. Page 51 mentions a setting for the start gear, the slider actually has 11 positions, suggesting that even if Shimano doesn't support this on Alfine-11 now, they might do it in the future. On page 53 the number of the hub's gear can be set up. The setting on the screenshot is 8, and it's not clear if other options are available.

Comment: I'm thinking about upgrading the rear wheel of my Bakfiets electric cargo bike. It has a DU-E6100 drive unit, and is currently equipped with a Nexus-7 gear hub. I find the 245% range of Nexus-7 to be not enough for me. For some reason, Bakfiets didn't (and still doesn't) offer the bike in a Nexus-8 version. They do offer it with Nexus-5 Di2 and auto shifting, or Nuvinci Enviolo. I am thinking about building a new rear wheel with an Alfine-11. I was also considering Alfine-8, but I don't know, it has only one gear more than my current hub, and a weirdly big jump between gears 5 and 6...

Comment: Found this page: https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/spec/E-BIKE/Drive%20Unit
For each drive unit, there's a list of hubs that can be used with auto shifting (search for "Automatic shift"). Not all drive units support auto shifting, but those that do, can only do it with 5 and 8 speed hubs (some can also do it with derailleurs).

Answer (score 1):

I got one answer from Shimano via Facebook (July 2017), but this is NOT CORRECT.
https://www.facebook.com/ShimanoEbike/

"Hi,
Do you know if the Shimano Alfine 11 has automatic shiftin possibilities with the STEPS systems? 
I to ask in many local shops, but they didn't know, I asked bike builders, but they didn't know. They only have bikes with Alfine 8, for which the automatic shifting works. I've looked into forums, checked your Shimano websites back and forth, but I didn't find any information.
I would be considering to buy a new bike with Steps and Alfine 11, if it has automatic shifting. If not, I would stay with Alfine 8. However, in our hilly city, Brussels, the Alfine 8 often feels not enough in range.
Thank you and kind regards,"

"Thanks for contacting. Shimano Alfine 11 speed hub is available with Shimano STEPS, but Alfine 8 isn't. Unfortunately automatic shifting is also not available yet in combination with STEPS. We can't guarantee this will be in the near future. 
Kind regards,
Team Shimano"